# Odoo 12 extend Graph view events with click on rect bar

Tags: javascript, events, controller, odoo, extend

I try to add some new event dispathcer to Graph view (click on graph bar)

```
odoo.define('myaddon.upgrades', function (require) {
    "use strict";   
    var GraphController = require('web.GraphController');
    GraphController.include({
        events: _.extend({}, GraphController.prototype.events, {
            'click rect.nv-bar': '_onBarClick',
        }),
        _onBarClick: function(event){
            console.log('bar clicked');
        },
    });
});
```

But *_onBarClick* never called. What's wrong?
During debug GraphController I even can see, that it really has events list including its default events and my added event too. Also if I add dispatcher to rect.nv-bar with JQuery at Chrome debug console, as

```
$('rect.nv-bar').click(function(e){console.log('bar clicked');});
```

it works too.
But something prevents it from run the way I quoted above. Maybe something inside the nvd3? How can I test it?

Comment: Have you added the .js file to the assets (should be in a xml file)? And can you probably add more code? It's difficult to exclude other parts of your module, because your code example looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, and all the other code from the same .js is executed as expected.

Comment: Can you add the XML code where your `rect.nv-bar` is used?

Comment: There is no xml. It is a part of nvd3 library integrated in default Odoo Graph view.

Comment: But there has to be some HTML in the end. How does that look?